# Filter runs of true values in an array by the intersection of true values in a second sparser array

Tags: python, dask, python-xarray

I have been banging my head against the wall with this for a bit. Any help is appreciated massively.

I have two boolean arrays (in reality two large xarray data arrays, substantially larger than memory, using dask, not chunked along the time dimension), dimensions are lat/lon/time. These data are: a1 = T/F was there precipitation? a2 = T/F was there intense precipitation?

I am interested in going through a1 along the time dimension finding groups of True values, and checking to see if there is a corresponding True value in a2 (in any of the index positions of the group in a1). If so include that run of True values in the result. if the run of true values does in a1 does not contain a corresponding True value in a2 then do not include the run in the results.

I am trying to keep this boolean (memory reasons), rather than resort to changing the data type to int, adding the two arrays together elementwise, then looking for runs with 2s in them, but if I need to resort to this method then I am not outright opposed.

I have a 1 dimensional minimum example here:

```
import numpy as np

def apply_mask(a1, a2):
    a1 = np.array(a1)
    a2 = np.array(a2)
    
    # Find runs of ones in a1
    runs, = np.where(np.diff(np.concatenate(([0], a1, [0]))) != 0)
    runs = runs.reshape(-1, 2)
    
    # Iterate over runs and apply mask a3
    for start, end in runs:
        if np.any(a3[start:end]):
            a1[start:end] = 1
        else:
            a1[start:end] = 0
    
    return a1.tolist()

a1 = [1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1]
a2 = [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]

a3 = apply_mask(a1, a2)
print("a3:", a3)
```

result:

```
a3: [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]
```

A 3D result would look like this (dims: lat:2, lon:2, time:3):

a1:

```
  [[[ True,  True, False],
    [ True,  True,  True]],
    
   [[ True,  False, True],
    [ False, False, False]]]
```

a2:

```
  [[[False, False, False],
    [False, False,  True]],

    [[False, False, True],
    [False, False, False]]])
```

result:

```
  [[[False, False, False],
    [True, True,  True]],

    [[False, False, True],
    [False, False, False]]]
```